# Can't send email to external emails in Workflow 2010 and 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, custom-list, outgoing-email

We are having an issue on sending out email to external users when using workflow 2010 or 2013.

We already did the steps in below URL's but still nothing works.

1. http://www.myclassbook.org/sharepoint-designer-2013-email-error/
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/59effc3a-9d48-4f5c-aef7-0969ca2f7bb1/how-can-i-configure-sp2013-custom-workflow-to-send-to-an-external-emailaddress?forum=sharepointcustomization
3. Added external user in AD

Is there anything that do we need to setup in our exchange server as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SP 2010 should send the email to external user. For 2013 we have limitation from MS so we would start and 2013 workflow, then call 2010 workflow from it to send mail to external users.

SP 2010 workflow - what error are you getting ?

Comment: Hi we don't received any error in workflow 2010.  It send the email to users under our domain including the email of the external user in our in box but the external user didn't received any email.

Comment: Any idea if mails getting blocked at exchange level. If no error in SP 2010 then i think, error is not related to SharePoint.

Comment: Is there way how we can check the mails that is getting blocked in exchange?

Comment: Do the telnet from server to check whether mails are going to external users. Below are the steps for telnet: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx

Comment: We also faced issue sometime back and found out that our system administrator had blocked sending outside mail from our sharepoint server